# how to initiate and maintain mongo shard replica set from mongos server?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-administration, database-performance, database-replication

I am trying to initiate a mongo shards replica set from mongos server, I want my mongos to maintain replica set and able to add new server to replication if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to [add a new shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/) to an existing cluster, you need to first create the replica set for the shard. As at MongoDB 3.6, you cannot run replica set management commands such as `rs.initiate()` or `rs.add()` via `mongos`: these commands need to be sent to the current primary for the replica set.

Once a new shard is successfully added to a deployment, the [sharded cluster balancer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/) will automatically take care of redistributing sharded collections to factor in the availability of the additional shard.

Comment: i just want to deploy normal mongo shards and i want to make them as a replica from running command 0n mongos , is this possible?

Comment: @sivanagireddy What you are asking for is not possible. A new shard replica set has to be configured and initiated via the primary `mongod` for the replica set before adding as a new shard via `mongos`.

Comment: sharding is not possible ok, can we initiate a replica set from monos, I mean take an ex(3 mongo and 1 mongos) I want to 3 mongo servers as the replica and I want to do that from mongos server.

Comment: @sivanagireddy The scenario is the same with or without sharded databases: if you want to initiate a replica set you need to do so via `mongod`, not a `mongos`. The `rs.initiate()` command needs to be sent directly to the intended primary. Once you have initiated a replica set, you can use [`sh.addShard()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.addShard/) via a `mongos` to add this replica set to a sharded deployment.